# Is it okay to call onClick on an anchor tag in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Folks,

I have an anchor tag inside my component like so:

```
class myComponent {

    render () {
        return (
            <a href="/link/to/other/page">Link</a>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to call an analytics function when user clicks on this tag like so:

```
analytics.submitData({event: "page redirection"});
```

Notice that I'm not setting state or calling any of the react functions.
Is it okay if I just call a function on the onClick event of the anchor tag? Something like this:

```
anchorClickHandler() {
    analytics.submitData({event: "page redirection"});
}
```

with

```
<a href="/link/to/other/page" onClick={this.anchorClickHandler.bind(this)}>Link</a>
```

Is there a better way to do this? 
Since as soon as the redirection happens the component unmount is called and I'm not sure my onClick handler will be called or not. Am I thinking something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your own element with a span for example :

```
<span className='sub' onClick={this.anchorClickHandler}>Link</span>
```

Apply the same styling to it using CSS (or inline CSS if this is a quick fix) :

```
.sub {
    cursor: pointer,
    color: blue
}
```

And then change your page in the function you showed us :

```
anchorClickHandler = event => {
    analytics.submitData({event: "page redirection"});
    // Navigate to /link/to/other/page
    window.location.href = '/link/to/other/page';
}
```

Comment: Instead of `window.location.href = //..` I'll be using `this.history.push()`. Thanks for the answer this. This is perfectly what I needed to know.

Comment: Alright, both function should work out for you. Glad I could help

Comment: You should not use a `span` element for a link as it becomes inaccessible for people navigating by keyboard.

Comment: This answer is outdated, dont use it nor the ones below

Answer (score 2):

It's is ok when call onClick on anchor tag.To prevent redirect when click on anchor tag you just call event.preventDefault()

```
anchorClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    analytics.submitData({event: "page redirection"});
    window.location.href = event.target.getAttribute('href');
}
```

Comment: I agree, but I think I need a better solution to `window.location.href = //..`

Comment: What do you mean by 'better' ?

Comment: may be `history.push` is better :))

Comment: @GiangLe Thanks a lot! That helped.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags are often abused with the onclick event to create pseudo-buttons by setting href to "#" or "javascript:void(0)" to prevent the page from refreshing.

These values cause unexpected behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window, bookmarking, and when JavaScript is still downloading, errors out, or is disabled. This also conveys incorrect semantics to assistive technologies (e.g., screen readers). In these cases, it is recommended to use a `<button>` instead. In general you should only use an anchor for navigation using a proper URL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why?

Comment: This is plain wrong, HTML does not care about the order of attributes you put in an element

Comment: @Treycos Thanks for pointing out. This answer confused me even more.

Comment: for reference refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Accessibility_concerns

Comment: This is a totally different answer